# Determine variable type under caret in a Visual Studio macro

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-macros

Is there a technique to determine the type under the cursor,`ActiveDocument.Selection`. I can use `DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.GoToDefinition")` to jump around the solution, and start parsing the file etc, but it seems a little kludgy.

I've tried using the *FileCodeModel*, but I cant get anything useful from it. I could be using it improperly though.

e.g:

```
void Foo()
{
 int i;
 SomeType st;

 i = 0;
 st = null;
}
```

If I placed the caret(or selection) on `i`, I'd like *int* as a result, if it was over `st`, I'd like *SomeType*, and if it was over the declaration of `SomeType`, again, I would like *SomeType* as an output.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to find all references see [How to implement find all reference?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vsx/thread/3d85e968-f735-420c-b9c8-d57ed7839d36/) and you can test references found (it is not very efficient and can be time consuming). Hovever I did not managed to make code example working (may be it should run from extension?)

Comment: I mention what you're talking about in my question. I'm looking for a method to avoid the `GoToDefinition` method. Using the GoToDefinition causes the IDE to jump about, which is annoying. All the same now, no more macros in 2012 :(

Comment: I appologize for not reading question carefully. So I have another hint.